# Azure Table Storage Storing a ulong

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Is there an azure table storage type that maps to a ulong? It seems like there isn't a very good way to store a number greater than Int64.MaxValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported data types currently are found on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx.  As you've seen ulong isn't one of them.

However, you can get around this by dealing with serialization/deserialization on your own.  If you are using the 2.0 or greater Storage library you can use the [ITableEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity.aspx) interface on your object, override the `ReadEntity` and `WriteEntity` methods.

Comment: Adding to MikeWo's answer: Other alternative could be to store them either as `Double` or `String` data type and do the conversion on client side. Both are capable of storing numbers bigger than Int64.MaxValue.

Comment: That sounds like it might be what I want but I may end up wrapping a property around the row key that parses it. Like:
public ulong MyProp {get{return ulong.Parse(PartionKey)};}
It looks like ulong properties don't actually get added as columns to tables (they don't even get added as strings) so I don't think I'll need to worry about that property being pushed up to table storage. It looks like I can't actually change the type of a row key anyway. I probably should have mentioned that the column that would have a ulong was the row key. If you notice anything completely wrong let me know!

Comment: You're correct. `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` properties are of `String` data type and can't be changed.